# Windows 10 DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE every other boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, bsod

Here is a description of the current behavior:

1. I boot the PC
2. GRUB menu appears, I select Windows 10
3. The login appears with background #1 (the background on the login screens change every other boot, and I can tell whether or not a BSoD will occur based on which background the login screen has)
4. Use the computer for ~5 min before `DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE` BSoD
5. Reboot
6. GRUB menu appears, I select Windows 10
7. The login appears with [background #2](https://filestore.community.support.microsoft.com/api/images/4ce87d03-e984-42c8-b383-753b71f2a0eb)

I dual boot with Ubuntu and my specs are

- GTX 1070
- i7 6700k
- 16 MB RAM
- 250 GB Samsung Evo SSD

Has anyone experienced anything like this?

Comment: share the dmp from C:\windows\minidump so that I can debug the issue

Comment: `C:\Windows\Minidump` is an empty directory...

Comment: Do you see the large file C:\windows\memory.dmp? If not, have you disabled the pagefile? this is required to get dumps.

Comment: I definitely see `C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP`, and it's large.

Comment: I couldn't use your link, I didn't have write access, also the url you sent had automatic download in that params. I've uploaded the file myself. [Here's the MEMORY.7z file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/04519ohxmbks6op/MEMORY.7z?dl=0)

Comment: the dump is corrupted. check your RAM with memtest86+ and look if the memory timings are ok (check in cpu-z that timings in memory and SPD tab match for the current speed)

Comment: have you tested the RAM?

Comment: Ran memtest86 not 86+, couldn't get that to boot. All of the tests passed. And the timings look fine.

Comment: you use the K CPU which allows OC. Do you OC the cpu? if yes, undo this.

Comment: I know my CPU can be OC'd, but I have never tried this. It's running at the base freq of 4.0 GHz

Comment: post some pictures of CPU-Z. Also run Samsung Magician to see if the SSD is fine. do you use the last firmware for the SSD?